# I got System.MissingMethodException .ctor on my Customization

Tags: acumatica

I'm having an error on my customization, in my instance it perfectly works, so I assumed it works the same when I deploy it.
[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe different customizations on your other instance. Are you using PXOverride to override something? are the versions of Acumatica the same? According to the exception description: "The exception that is thrown when there is an attempt to dynamically access a method that does not exist." so my guess something to do with a PXOverride. Post the code sample that causes the issue? Try to replicate the same environment locally (versions, customizations, etc. and turn on debugging)

Comment: I might say that these are two different major versions, not build. I was designing a customization that can be deployed version independently, but I guess I'm wrong I still need to have a copy for each Major Version I will handee